# Energy minimum of a solid compared to energy minimum of a particle pair

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

If I take a pair of classical particles with some energy interacting via Lennard-Jones potential, then the motion of the two particles will be in such a way that the distance oscillates around the equilibrium point (if the energy is not too high compared to barrier depth).

If I consider a large number of Lennard Jones particles packed into a crystalline lattice, then intuitively I expect that each pair of particles should have a distance close to the equilibrium distance of the pair potential. In other words the "lattice constant" should be close to the equilibrium of the pair potential.

But is it actually the case ? Can we consider a pair of neighbors in a Lennard-Jones lattice to be roughly an equilibrium of the pair potential with small corrections of further particles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the intuition that

> each pair of particles should have a distance close to the equilibrium distance of the pair potential.

may be off if one considers solids in different dimensionalities and interaction laws. In the particular case of a Lennard-Jones (LJ) 12-6 solid in three dimensions, numbers confirm the "intuitive" expectation. For a 12-6 Lennard-Jones pair interaction
$$
\phi(r) = 4 \varepsilon \left[  \left(  \frac{\sigma}{r}  \right)^{12}   -  \left(  \frac{\sigma}{r}  \right)^{6}   \right]
$$
the minimum of the pairwise energy is at $\bar r_{pair}=2^{\frac16} \sigma \simeq 1.12 \sigma$.

In a solid of LJ particles, one can expect a first neighbor distance shorter than $\bar r_{pair}$ because there is an effect of the farther neighbors. The optimal (minimum) energy is obtained from a competition between a slight reduction of the nearest neighbor distance, which would increase the energy, and an overcompensating decrease of the energy due to the increased weight of the attractive contributions from the second and farther neighbors. A calculation reported in every solid-state textbook gives an equilibrium distance of $1.09 \sigma$, confirming a small but sizable reduction of the equilibrium distance.

Comment: Thanks. From solid-state textbooks I only recall the Madelung constant (or Madelung calculation) for electrostatic potentials. I would have a closer look then.